# LIMIT in SQL query returning MAX amount specified

Tags: mysql

For some reason this is always returning 31 row instead of the expected 2 rows. Not really certain what is going on?

```
SELECT 
    ins_by          AS userid,
    wds_user_id     AS customer, 
    wds_address_id  AS billing,
    (
        SELECT 
            wds_address_id  AS shipping
        FROM 
            wds_user_address B
        WHERE 
            ins_by != "GUEST" 
        AND 
            wds_address_type_id = 2 
        AND 
            B.ins_by = A.ins_by
    ) AS shipping
FROM 
    wds_user_address A 
WHERE 
    ins_by != "GUEST" 
AND 
    wds_address_type_id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 30, 32;
```

Expecting

```
+---------------------+----------+---------+----------+
| userid              | customer | billing | shipping |
+---------------------+----------+---------+----------+
| FOO@GMAIL.COM       |      121 |     185 |      186 |
| BAR@GMAIL.COM       |      123 |     189 |      190 |
+---------------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Did you mean `LIMIT 30, 2`?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is telling MySQL to return 32 rows.

```
LIMIT 30,32
```

That says "skip the first 30 rows, and then return the next 32 rows".

If you want to skip the first 30 rows and return only the next 2 rows, your LIMIT clause needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just replace the limit with 30,2. Like below query

```
SELECT 
    ins_by          AS userid,
    wds_user_id     AS customer, 
    wds_address_id  AS billing,
    (
        SELECT 
            wds_address_id  AS shipping
        FROM 
            wds_user_address B
        WHERE 
            ins_by != "GUEST" 
        AND 
            wds_address_type_id = 2 
        AND 
            B.ins_by = A.ins_by
    ) AS shipping
FROM 
    wds_user_address A 
WHERE 
    ins_by != "GUEST" 
AND 
    wds_address_type_id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 30, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LIMIt 30, 32
```

Equals to

Move the pointer to the 30th row, and get the next 32 rows.

Change it to

```
LIMIT 30, 2
```

If you want it to return 2 rows.